# currentTime not working with flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, mediaelement.js

I am using mediaelement.js as an audio player. Why currentTime not working with flash on opera? Any solution for this? The currentTime only working with html5?

**Example :**    http://bit.ly/1Mi40Rx

```js
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player audio',
           { success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
               
                var TimePlayed = parseInt($.cookie('Played'));
                 
                 $('.time').text(TimePlayed); 
                
                mediaElement.play(); 
           
            mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
             
             $.cookie('Played', mediaElement.currentTime);  
            
             
               }, false);  }
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.18.1/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.18.1/mediaelementplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<div id="player">

  <audio type="audio/mp3" controls="controls">
    <Source src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/AirReview-Landmarks-02-ChasingCorporate.mp3"></Source>
  </audio>

</div>

<div class="time"></div>
```